# Table headers not shown android

Tags: java, android, tableview

I am unable to view headers in the following code.

***activity_main.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="am.dx.narmadaa.graytable_trial1.MainActivity"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    />

   <include layout="@layout/content_table_gray"/>

   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>`
```

***content_table_gray.xml***

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="am.dx.narmadaa.graytable_trial1.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

  <de.codecrafters.tableview.TableView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/gray_table"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

***MainActivity.java***

```
    package am.dx.narmadaa.graytable_trial1;

    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.ProtocolException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import de.codecrafters.tableview.TableView;
    import de.codecrafters.tableview.toolkit.SimpleTableDataAdapter;
    import de.codecrafters.tableview.toolkit.SimpleTableHeaderAdapter;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String[][] table_data;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

    final String json_head[] = {"Sl No","Entry Date","Lot no","Party","Total pcs","Total mtrs","Total wt","Count","Variety","Gray Width","Finishing Width","Remarks","SLUO","LUUser","GPM"};

    final TableView<String[]> tableView;

    tableView = findViewById(R.id.gray_table);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            String[][] json_data = {{"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15"}};
            tableView.setColumnCount(15);
            tableView.setHeaderBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("YELLOW"));
            tableView.setHeaderAdapter(new SimpleTableHeaderAdapter(MainActivity.this,json_head));
            tableView.setDataAdapter(new SimpleTableDataAdapter(MainActivity.this,json_data));
        }
    });
}

public String[][] returnData(ArrayList<GrayHelper> grayHelpers)
{
    table_data = new String[grayHelpers.size()][15];

    GrayHelper gh;

    for (int i=0; i < grayHelpers.size();i++)
    {
        gh = grayHelpers.get(i);
        table_data[i][0] = gh.getSlno();
        table_data[i][1] = gh.getEd();
        table_data[i][2] = gh.getLno();
        table_data[i][3] = gh.getPar();
        table_data[i][4] = gh.getPcs();
        table_data[i][5] = gh.getMts();
        table_data[i][6] = gh.getWt();
        table_data[i][7] = gh.getCt();
        table_data[i][8] = gh.getVar();
        table_data[i][9] = gh.getGw();
        table_data[i][10] = gh.getFw();
        table_data[i][11] = gh.getRemarks();
        table_data[i][12] = gh.getSluo();
        table_data[i][13] = gh.getLuuser();
        table_data[i][14] = gh.getGpm();
    }

    return table_data;
}

public class ServerFetch extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>
{

    String[][] json_encoded;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids)
    {
        String json_url = "" ;

        try
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            URL url = new URL(json_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (ProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        /*try {
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }*/
    }
}

    //Class for parsing data
public class GrayHelper
{
    //Instance Variables

    private String slno;
    private String ed;
    private String lno;
    private String par;
    private String pcs;
    private String mts;
    private String wt;
    private String ct;
    private String var;
    private String gw;
    private String fw;
    private String remarks;
    private String sluo;
    private String luuser;
    private String gpm;

    //Getters

    public String getSlno()
    {
        return slno;
    }

    public String getEd() {
        return ed;
    }

    public String getLno() {
        return lno;
    }

    public String getPar() {
        return par;
    }

    public String getPcs() {
        return pcs;
    }

    public String getMts() {
        return mts;
    }

    public String getWt() {
        return wt;
    }

    public String getCt() {
        return ct;
    }

    public String getVar() {
        return var;
    }

    public String getGw() {
        return gw;
    }

    public String getFw() {
        return fw;
    }

    public String getRemarks() {
        return remarks;
    }

    public String getSluo() {
        return sluo;
    }

    public String getLuuser() {
        return luuser;
    }

    public String getGpm() {
        return gpm;
    }

    //Setters

    public void setSlno(String slno) {
        this.slno = slno;
    }

    public void setEd(String ed) {
        this.ed = ed;
    }

    public void setLno(String lno) {
        this.lno = lno;
    }

    public void setPar(String par) {
        this.par = par;
    }

    public void setPcs(String pcs) {
        this.pcs = pcs;
    }

    public void setMts(String mts) {
        this.mts = mts;
    }

    public void setWt(String wt) {
        this.wt = wt;
    }

    public void setCt(String ct) {
        this.ct = ct;
    }

    public void setVar(String var) {
        this.var = var;
    }

    public void setGw(String gw) {
        this.gw = gw;
    }

    public void setFw(String fw) {
        this.fw = fw;
    }

    public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
        this.remarks = remarks;
    }

    public void setSluo(String sluo) {
        this.sluo = sluo;
    }

    public void setLuuser(String luuser) {
        this.luuser = luuser;
    }

    public void setGpm(String gpm) {
        this.gpm = gpm;
    }
        }
    }
```

Is this due to the fact that i have used more than 10 columns to display?
I am unable to view even a single header. And also when i view the data only the first nine values are displayed irrespective of the total number of values.So anyone help me with this issue....

Comment: Try to use `SortableTableView` XML and Java instead of using `TableView`

Comment: That didn't help

Comment: Why don't you use https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView instead of this ?